# Trying to add Magicmouse.js to custom wordpress theme - Cant get it to load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Im building out a WP theme from the ground up and I have added tye js and css files for mightmouse.js to my themes css and js directory. I have enqueued both of the elements in the fuctions.php file using

```
function cursor_javascript() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousemagic-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magic_mouse.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cursor_javascript' );

function cursor_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mousemagic-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/magic-mouse.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cursor_stylesheets' );
```

I am trying to get the cursor to show on all pages but im not getting it to present itself. When I use inspect on the page i can see the elements being loaded in. How would I go about adding the function to each page gloablly without using any plugins?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise `magicmouse` after loading it.

Create a new script within your theme directory, e.g. `magicmouse.local.js` and in the file put the initialisation call.

For example this is the content of `magicmouse.local.js`:

```
options = {
  "cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
  "hoverEffect": "circle-move",
  "hoverItemMove": false,
  "defaultCursor": false,
  "outerWidth": 30,
  "outerHeight": 30
}
magicMouse(options);
```

Then load this script as well with `wp_enqueue_script`

For example this is the updated function

```
function cursor_javascript() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousemagic-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magic_mouse.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'mousemagic-js-local', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magicmouse.local.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cursor_javascript' );
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example of how you can enqueue it

Comment: When I enqueue it as a separate script I still cant get the cursor to show on the page at all.  Looking at the source its loading the css and js for magicmouse and afterward I enqueue the script with the cursor options to call it forward but still nothing. hmmm, Im a bit of a noob with using js so maybe im doing something wrong with initializing it?

Comment: Can you see the new `magicmouse.local.js` script in the source of the page? Does it contain the correct code?

Comment: Also, have you check your browser JS console for errors?

Comment: getting an error in the console of...........magic_mouse.js?ver=5.7.2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at magicMouse (magic_mouse.js?ver=5.7.2:1)
    at VM57 cursor.js:9
magicMouse @ magic_mouse.js?ver=5.7.2:1
(anonymous) @ VM57 cursor.js:9

Comment: You mention that you can't see the mouse cursor at all. Is it possible that it's just white and your page is white as well? Have you tried changing the CSS to be black instead of white? Specifically `body #magicMouseCursor{border-color:black} body #magicPointer{background:black}body #magicPointer.pointer-blur{border-color:black}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @Andrea Oliviato!

Issue has been solved.

The issue was lying with me not encapsulating the local js script properly. I have used the following;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  options = {
    "cursorOuter": "circle-basic",
    "hoverEffect": "circle-move",
    "hoverItemMove": false,
    "defaultCursor": false,
    "outerWidth": 30,
    "outerHeight": 30
    }
  magicMouse(options);
})
```

The cursor function is working beautifully thank you!